# How to login to an email Address using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am testing some api for our product using jmeter. To test the api to verify the user's email address I need to login to the mail account. I have the email and password of a test user. How can I login using an api or any other way in jmeter?

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. You'll have to create a test plan with multiple steps but these depend on the concrete implementation of the login.

First you must identify the following two locations:

- The GET request that gets the initial login form (if this is required).
- The POST request that posts the login credentials.

If your service has a stateless login form you can even skip the first step.

Otherwise the response of the GET request will contain stuff which needs to be extracted (e.g. the JSESSIONID if you are using JSF) and sent as a parameters in the POST request. You can use the `Regular Expression Extractor` of JMeter to extract these values and provide them as variables for use in the subsequent requests.

Here is an example screenshot of a `HTTP Request` element configured to POST login data to the url `/common/j_security_check`

[image: POST request example]

Comment: Don't i require the api url for the get and post request? I m sorry if this is a naive question.

Comment: Yes, you can modify the api url in the PATH field.

Comment: I meant the URL of the API to login. How do i get that?

Comment: You have to find out that URL from the code. It is probably the action target of the login form POST.

Comment: That would be the URl to log in to my website right? I need an api to log in to that email-address. N how would i have the password to authenticate? I m sorry, I m lost.

Comment: Yes the URI to login to your website is the URI to login to your website...? Maybe you can update your initial question with the source code of your login page and the URI with which you access it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to intercept an authentication token from the server response and then pass that into following requests.

Here is a blog entry with a couple of video tutorials on logins with JMeter:
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication

Comment: Ok I m going to clarify my question. The user enter's an email-address and we send an authentication token as a link to that email-address. User clicks on that to confirm the email-address. Now this "click-on-link" needs to be replicated in J-meter. The api does not return the authentication token in the response. :( Did i not understand your answer correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jmeter to login,
two ways:
parameterization using csv file(for more users)/user defined variables(UDV)
Login config elements(for single user)

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand you want to automatically click on a confirmation link from an email using JMeter, here is a blog entry that explains exactly how to do that:

http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url

Ophir